# Uncompress a TIFF file without going through BufferedImage

Tags: java, tiff, jai, javax.imageio

I am receiving large size CCITT Group 4 compressed TIFF files that need to be written elsewhere as uncompressed TIFF files. I am using the jai_imageio TIFF reader and writer to do that and it works well as long as the product _width * height_ of the image fits in an integer.

Here is the code I am using:

```
TIFFImageReaderSpi readerSpi= new TIFFImageReaderSpi();
ImageReader imageReader = readerSpi.createReaderInstance();
byte[] data = blobManager.getObjectForIdAndVersion(id, version);
ImageInputStream imageInputStream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(data); 
imageReader.setInput(imageInputStream);

TIFFImageWriterSpi writerSpi = new TIFFImageWriterSpi();
ImageWriter imageWriter = writerSpi.createWriterInstance();
ImageWriteParam imageWriteParam = imageWriter.getDefaultWriteParam();
imageWriteParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_DISABLED);
//bufferFile is created in the constructor
ImageOutputStream imageOutputStream = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(bufferFile);
imageWriter.setOutput(imageOutputStream);

//Now read the bitmap
BufferedImage bufferedImage = imageReader.read(0);
IIOImage iIOImage = new IIOImage(bufferedImage, null, null);
//and write it
imageWriter.write(null, iIOImage, imageWriteParam);
```

Unfortunately, the files that I receive are often very large and the BufferedImage cannot be created.
I have been trying to find a way to stream from the ImageReader directly to the ImageWriter but I cannot find out how to do that.
Anybody with a suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the some issues, and the end result might surprise you :

I ended up calling IrfanView with some command-line options using the Runtime.exec() method. That way, I am not worried about compression or size, it just works and outputs the correct files in the correct folder for me.

If you are on Linux, you can use ImageMagik or something similar.

Comment: Thanks but that is not an option for me. First of all because it is not open source and runs under Windows only. If I would decide to use native code I could quite easily write my own uncompressor using libtiff.

Comment: You could do the same thing using ImageMagik on Linux :)

Comment: My question is about the JAI classes. I know there are other solutions outside the Java ennvironment but that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: As soon as your array grows outside the range of an integer, you run into trouble. Perhaps there's a way to partition the image?

Answer (score 1):

You can use TIFF tiles to segment a TIFF into smaller portions ("tiles"). If you control the code creating the big images, JAI allows you to retrieve image content tile-by-tile.

Here is an example on how to create tiled image with JAI:

```
ColorModel cm = source.createColorModel();
// SampleModel with the tilesize
SampleModel sm = cm.createCompatibleSampleModel(tileWidth, tileHeight);
TiledImage image = new TiledImage(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight, 0, 0, sm, cm);

TIFFEncodeParam tep = new TIFFEncodeParam();
tep.setTileSize(tileWidth, tileHeight); // Set tile size to avoid OOM
tep.setWriteTiled(true);
JAI.create("filestore", image, filepath, "TIFF", tep);
```

If you can't control the TIFF production, my knowledge of JAI is too limited to be of much help.

Answer (score 0):

Give your Java VM more memory.

If that doesn't work, look at the [source code of the TIFF plugin in the JAI source code](http://java.net/projects/jai-imageio-core/sources/svn/show/trunk/src/share/classes/com/sun/media/imageioimpl/plugins/tiff). You might be able to write your own processor which just decompresses the data structures using a streaming approach (so you'll never have to keep the whole image in memory at any time).

If that also doesn't work, look at [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) which allows you to call code from a DLL from Java (no C code required; everything is done from pure Java, unlike with Sun's JNI API).

Comment: Thanks, but it has nothing to do with VM Memory. The problem is that the image data array grows larger than the max value of an integer. I could indeed fork the JAI code but that is something I would like to avoid. JNA sounds like an interesting project but JNI works well for me in other places. I just wanted to avoid having to solve this issue externally, but by the looks of it that doesn't seem possible.